# calling methods in a jar file from php

Tags: java, php, jar, executable-jar

I am running a jar file from the php function.

```
exec("java -jar hel.jar", $outputArray);
```

But i want to call a particular method in the jar file and send parameters to those methods and get the final output.

Example:-

```
public class hel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         hel he=new hel();
        he.getName("john");
    }

   public String getName(String name){
        System.out.println(name);
        return name;

    }

}
```

I want to send a String value as parameter to method "getName" and get the final output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you read up on the Java `CLASSPATH`? It allows you to do exactly this.

Comment: CLASSPATH refered to add more classes right? i want to run a specific method in jar file by adding parameters to it.

Comment: Java has methods in it to do this. You don't need to call the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can only call the `main` method from the main class. From the java manual:

> -jar filename
>
> Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The filename
>      argument is the name of a JAR file with a manifest that contains a
>      line in the form Main-Class:classname that defines the class with
>      the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as
>      your application's starting point.

So for it to work you have to setup your manifest in the jar and write your main class to call the function you want. When that's done, append any arguments to the `exec` call and it should work.

You have to create a manifest file "MANIFEST.MF" in the "META-INF" folder of the jar with these contents:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: This.Is.Your.Package.hel

and you can add arguments to exec like this:

```
exec("java -jar hel.jar first_argument second_argument", $outputArray);
```

add quotes if your arguments need spaces. Your arguments will show up in the `String[] args` array.

Comment: could be plz explain me bit more about this solution? im stucked in this. What changes do i need to make in the manifest? how to append arguments to exec? its only taking arguments for the "args" right?

Comment: small questions.I tried this method.These arguments will be considering as parameters for "args" right? (String [] args)?? Where should i enter my method name?

Comment: Yes, those arguments will be passed on to the main method's parameter "args". Method name can only be "main", you can't choose other method name, so you don't need to enter it.